# ReactJS: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: jquery, reactjs

Estoy tratando de llamar una función dentro de un componente en ReactJs la cual tiene código Javascript realizado con jQuery pero este me da el siguiente error en consola

[image: Este es el error que me da en la consola Javascript]

mientras tanto el depurador de React me da este error

```
./src/utils/HomeEffects.js
  Line 6:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 10:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 14:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 87:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 92:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Los archivos involucrados son los siguientes

## HomeEffects.js

```
import $ from 'jquery';

export function HomeEffects() {
    var resizefunc = [];

    !function ($) {
        "use strict";

        var Sidemenu = function () {
            this.$body = $("body"),
                this.$openLeftBtn = $(".open-left"),
                this.$menuItem = $("#sidebar-menu a")
        };
        Sidemenu.prototype.openLeftBar = function () {
            $("#main").toggleClass("enlarged");
            $("#main").addClass("forced");

            if ($("#main").hasClass("enlarged") && $("body").hasClass("adminbody")) {
                $("body").removeClass("adminbody").addClass("adminbody-void");
            } else if (!$("#main").hasClass("enlarged") && $("body").hasClass("adminbody-void")) {
                $("body").removeClass("adminbody-void").addClass("adminbody");
            }

            if ($("#main").hasClass("enlarged")) {
                $(".left ul").removeAttr("style");
            } else {
                $(".subdrop").siblings("ul:first").show();
            }

        },
            //menu item click
            Sidemenu.prototype.menuItemClick = function (e) {
                if (!$("#main").hasClass("enlarged")) {
                    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("submenu")) {

                    }
                    if (!$(this).hasClass("subdrop")) {
                        // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
                        $("ul", $(this).parents("ul:first")).slideUp(350);
                        $("a", $(this).parents("ul:first")).removeClass("subdrop");
                        $("#sidebar-menu .pull-right i").removeClass("md-remove").addClass("md-add");

                        // open our new menu and add the open class
                        $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
                        $(this).addClass("subdrop");
                        $(".pull-right i", $(this).parents(".submenu:last")).removeClass("md-add").addClass("md-remove");
                        $(".pull-right i", $(this).siblings("ul")).removeClass("md-remove").addClass("md-add");
                    } else if ($(this).hasClass("subdrop")) {
                        $(this).removeClass("subdrop");
                        $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
                        $(".pull-right i", $(this).parent()).removeClass("md-remove").addClass("md-add");
                    }
                }
            },

            //init sidemenu
            Sidemenu.prototype.init = function () {
                var $this = this;

                var ua = navigator.userAgent,
                    event = (ua.match(/iP/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";

                //bind on click
                this.$openLeftBtn.on(event, function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $this.openLeftBar();
                });

                // LEFT SIDE MAIN NAVIGATION
                $this.$menuItem.on(event, $this.menuItemClick);

                // NAVIGATION HIGHLIGHT & OPEN PARENT
                $("#sidebar-menu ul li.submenu a.active").parents("li:last").children("a:first").addClass("active").trigger("click");
            },

            //init Sidemenu
            $.Sidemenu = new Sidemenu, $.Sidemenu.Constructor = Sidemenu

    }(window.jQuery),


        //main app module
        function ($) {
            "use strict";

            var App = function () {
                this.pageScrollElement = "html, body",
                    this.$body = $("body")
            };

            //on doc load
            App.prototype.onDocReady = function (e) {
               //FastClick.attach(document.body);
                resizefunc.push("changeptype");

                $('.animate-number').each(function () {
                    $(this).animateNumbers($(this).attr("data-value"), true, parseInt($(this).attr("data-duration")));
                });

                //RUN RESIZE ITEMS
                $(window).resize(debounce(resizeitems, 100));
                $("body").trigger("resize");

                // right side-bar toggle
                $('.right-bar-toggle').on('click', function (e) {

                    $('#main').toggleClass('right-bar-enabled');
                });


            },
                //initilizing
                App.prototype.init = function () {
                    var $this = this;
                    $(document).ready($this.onDocReady);
                    $.Sidemenu.init();
                },

                $.App = new App, $.App.Constructor = App

        }(window.jQuery),

        //initializing main application module
        function ($) {
            "use strict";
            $.App.init();
        }(window.jQuery);


    function executeFunctionByName(functionName, context) {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments).splice(2);
        var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
        var func = namespaces.pop();
        for (var i = 0; i  990) {
                $("body").removeClass("smallscreen").addClass("widescreen");
                $("#main").removeClass("enlarged");
            } else {
                $("body").removeClass("widescreen").addClass("smallscreen");
                $("#main").addClass("enlarged");
                $(".left ul").removeAttr("style");
            }
            if ($("#main").hasClass("enlarged") && $("body").hasClass("adminbody")) {
                $("body").removeClass("adminbody").addClass("adminbody-void");
            } else if (!$("#main").hasClass("enlarged") && $("body").hasClass("adminbody-void")) {
                $("body").removeClass("adminbody-void").addClass("adminbody");
            }

        }

    }


    var debounce = function (func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout, result;
        return function () {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function () {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) result = func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) result = func.apply(context, args);
            return result;
        };
    }

    function resizeitems() {
        if ($.isArray(resizefunc)) {
            for (var i = 0; i
```

y el siguiente es el archivo principal donde hago el llamado de esa funcion para que se ejecute al cargar la aplicacion

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './components/home/Home';
import FrequentQuestions from './components/information/frequentQuestions/FrequentQuestions';
import './css/App.css';
import { HomeEffects } from './utils/HomeEffects';

//import { fastClick } from './utils/fastClick';
//import { detect } from './utils/detect';

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: "/faq",
        component: FrequentQuestions
    }
];

class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
       
        
        HomeEffects(); // AQUI LLAMO A LA FUNCION QUE DESEO EJECUTAR
    }

    render() {
        return (
            Render
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

---

## Actualizacion

cambie las lineas en el codigo por el siguiente

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;


export function HomeEffects() {
    var resizefunc = [];

    !function ($) {
        "use strict";

        var Sidemenu = function () {
            this.$body = $("body"),
                this.$openLeftBtn = $(".open-left"),
                this.$menuItem = $("#sidebar-menu a")
        };
        Sidemenu.prototype.openLeftBar = function () {
            $("#main").toggleClass("enlarged");
            $("#main").addClass("forced");

            if ($("#main").hasClass("enlarged") && $("body").hasClass("adminbody")) {
                $("body").removeClass("adminbody").addClass("adminbody-void");
            } else if (!$("#main").hasClass("enlarged") && $("body").hasClass("adminbody-void")) {
                $("body").removeClass("adminbody-void").addClass("adminbody");
            }

            if ($("#main").hasClass("enlarged")) {
                $(".left ul").removeAttr("style");
            } else {
                $(".subdrop").siblings("ul:first").show();
            }

        },
            //menu item click
            Sidemenu.prototype.menuItemClick = function (e) {
                if (!$("#main").hasClass("enlarged")) {
                    if ($(this).parent().hasClass("submenu")) {

                    }
                    if (!$(this).hasClass("subdrop")) {
                        // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
                        $("ul", $(this).parents("ul:first")).slideUp(350);
                        $("a", $(this).parents("ul:first")).removeClass("subdrop");
                        $("#sidebar-menu .pull-right i").removeClass("md-remove").addClass("md-add");

                        // open our new menu and add the open class
                        $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
                        $(this).addClass("subdrop");
                        $(".pull-right i", $(this).parents(".submenu:last")).removeClass("md-add").addClass("md-remove");
                        $(".pull-right i", $(this).siblings("ul")).removeClass("md-remove").addClass("md-add");
                    } else if ($(this).hasClass("subdrop")) {
                        $(this).removeClass("subdrop");
                        $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
                        $(".pull-right i", $(this).parent()).removeClass("md-remove").addClass("md-add");
                    }
                }
            },

            //init sidemenu
            Sidemenu.prototype.init = function () {
                var $this = this;

                var ua = navigator.userAgent,
                    event = (ua.match(/iP/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";

                //bind on click
                this.$openLeftBtn.on(event, function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    $this.openLeftBar();
                });

                // LEFT SIDE MAIN NAVIGATION
                $this.$menuItem.on(event, $this.menuItemClick);

                // NAVIGATION HIGHLIGHT & OPEN PARENT
                $("#sidebar-menu ul li.submenu a.active").parents("li:last").children("a:first").addClass("active").trigger("click");
            },

            //init Sidemenu
            $.Sidemenu = new Sidemenu, $.Sidemenu.Constructor = Sidemenu

    }(window.jQuery),


        //main app module
        function ($) {
            "use strict";

            var App = function () {
                this.pageScrollElement = "html, body",
                    this.$body = $("body")
            };

            //on doc load
            App.prototype.onDocReady = function (e) {
               //FastClick.attach(document.body);
                resizefunc.push("changeptype");

                $('.animate-number').each(function () {
                    $(this).animateNumbers($(this).attr("data-value"), true, parseInt($(this).attr("data-duration")));
                });

                //RUN RESIZE ITEMS
                $(window).resize(debounce(resizeitems, 100));
                $("body").trigger("resize");

                // right side-bar toggle
                $('.right-bar-toggle').on('click', function (e) {

                    $('#main').toggleClass('right-bar-enabled');
                });


            },
                //initilizing
                App.prototype.init = function () {
                    var $this = this;
                    $(document).ready($this.onDocReady);
                    $.Sidemenu.init();
                },

                $.App = new App, $.App.Constructor = App

        }(window.jQuery),

        //initializing main application module
        function ($) {
            "use strict";
            $.App.init();
        }(window.jQuery);


    function executeFunctionByName(functionName, context) {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments).splice(2);
        var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
        var func = namespaces.pop();
        for (var i = 0; i  990) {
                $("body").removeClass("smallscreen").addClass("widescreen");
                $("#main").removeClass("enlarged");
            } else {
                $("body").removeClass("widescreen").addClass("smallscreen");
                $("#main").addClass("enlarged");
                $(".left ul").removeAttr("style");
            }
            if ($("#main").hasClass("enlarged") && $("body").hasClass("adminbody")) {
                $("body").removeClass("adminbody").addClass("adminbody-void");
            } else if (!$("#main").hasClass("enlarged") && $("body").hasClass("adminbody-void")) {
                $("body").removeClass("adminbody-void").addClass("adminbody");
            }

        }

    }


    var debounce = function (func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout, result;
        return function () {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function () {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) result = func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) result = func.apply(context, args);
            return result;
        };
    }

    function resizeitems() {
        if ($.isArray(resizefunc)) {
            for (var i = 0; i
```

y me da ahora el siguiente error

```
./src/utils/HomeEffects.js
  Line 8:     Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 12:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 16:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 89:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 94:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 143:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 144:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 145:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 146:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 149:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 152:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 154:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 155:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 157:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 158:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 159:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 161:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 161:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 162:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 163:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 163:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 164:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef
  Line 189:  '$' is not defined                                                     no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: Solo por curiosidad... ¿Por que no usas javascript y eliminas el uso de Jquery? Si no te dejo un link donde indican el uso correcto de Jquery con React JS [Implementación Jquery en React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-with-reactjs#answer-41381583)

Answer (score 2):

El error está en que estás pasando `window.jQuery` a las IIFE que declaras:

```
function ($) {
  "use strict";
  $.App.init();
}(window.jQuery); // aquí está el error
```

Esto ocurre porque `window.jQuery` no tiene ningún valor porque estás usando [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) como [ES Module](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html).

Para solucionar el error puedes eliminar las referencias a `window.jQuery` o establecer `$` a `window.jQuery` fuera de la función principal.

```
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;
```

Comment: me dice lo siguiente ´HomeEffects.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined´

Comment: @AnthonyMedina actualiza tu pregunta con el nuevo código por favor.

Comment: listo, ya agregue los cambios

Comment: @AnthonyMedina Sospecho que hay un conflicto en algún lado. ¿Te marca error en la función `executeFunctionByName`?